# How do I modify this query to return All Address that have the Same Zip, but different City?

Tags: sql

Given the following query:

```
SELECT Address,
City,
Zip 
FROM dbo.tblX
```

How do I modify this query to return all addresses (`tblX`) where another row exists with the Same `Zip`, but different `City`?

Comment: Please don't down vote, I have been trying to write subqueries to pull back these results with no success. I tried to keep the description simple so I could get some help.

Comment: @AndyWilliams It's often helpful to show what you're tried (even if it's completely wrong) so answers can guide you to an answer that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of queries a [correlated sub-query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) is useful:

```
SELECT Address,City,Zip 
FROM dbo.tblX AS x
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 0
   FROM dbo.tblX 
   WHERE Zip = x.Zip
       AND City <> x.City
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified this query slightly to get back the specific addresses I was looking for but this aided me in my search!      SELECT Address,City,Zip 
FROM dbo.tblX AS x
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 0
   FROM dbo.tblX
   WHERE Zip = x.Zip
       AND City <> x.City
    AND Address = x.Address
)
AND x.City IS NOT NULL
AND x.Address IS NOT NULL

Comment: I fail to understand the question. Your answer is accepted so I guess is good. Still don't get what the question is.

Comment: @TheImpaler The question is "show me all records where _another record exists_ with the same ZIP but a different City". I inferred the italicised part.

Comment: OK, got you. I edited the question, and upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a Group By to get a list of Zip+City>1, then pull all records with those zip codes. Here I'm using a CTE at the top, but you can also use a subquery at the bottom, depending on what database you're using:

```
; WITH MismatchZip
AS (
    SELECT City,
        Zip
    FROM dbo.tblX
    GROUP BY City
        , Zip
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    )
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblX x
    JOIN MismatchZip z
        ON x.Zip = z.Zip
```